# One part of html page disappeared in google but it is normal in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

One part of this html page disappeared in google chrome,but it is OK in firefox .I check the console part of browser ,every element is right,but it just can't appear in google chrome.here are the pictures,I add a roll animation to the two little balls.I don't think it was the animation cause the disappearence, because I delete the animation jquery file,but nothing changed...

```
<div class="advantage" >
<div class="adv_wrapper">
<div class="adv_header">
    <div class="line2 horizon2"></div>
    <div class="adv_title horizon2">ADVANTAGE</div>
    <div class="line2 horizon2"></div>
</div>
<div class="adv_content">
    <div class="ball_content">
        <div class="ball1 ball">
            <div class="ball1_inner"><img src="images/adv/left.png"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ball2 ball"></div>
        <div class="ball3 ball">
            <div class="ball3_inner"><img src="images/adv/right.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="target"></div>
    <div class="target_des">
        <a class="szll item" href="">AAA</a>
        <a class="zczz item" href="">BBB</a>
        <a class="yjjs item" href="">CCC</a>
        <a class="zyhz item" href="">DDD</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.advantage .target{
width: 100%;
height: 340px;
background:url(../images/adv/target.png);
/*border:solid 1px red;*/
}
.target_des{
/*border:solid 1px black;*/
height: 100px;
}
.target_des>.item{
float: left;
font-family: "黑体";
font-size: 18px;
color: rgb(160,160,167);
width: 90px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px;
/*border:solid 1px red;*/
}
.target_des>.item::after {
content: "";
border-radius: 5px;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
transform: background-color .3s;
}
.target_des>.item:hover {
background-color: rgb(30,148,211);
color: white;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
}

.target_des>.item:hover::after {
opacity: 1;
}
.szll{
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 165px;
}
.zczz{
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 300px;
}
.yjjs{
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 170px;
}
```

js:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 setInterval(function(){
    $(".ball1_inner").addClass("roll-left").one('animationend',function(){
        $(this).removeClass("roll-left");
        $(".ball3_inner").addClass("roll-right").one('animationend',function(){
            $(this).removeClass("roll-right");
        })
    })
},8000);
})
```

in google chrome

[image]

in firefox

[image]